# Is is possible to Override ASP.NET Identity's ApplicationUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, overriding, asp.net-identity-2

When attempting to add on Override void ParseEntity and get the following error message:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0115  'ApplicationUser.ParseEntity(ref ApplicationUser)': no suitable method found to override ...\Models\IdentityModels.cs   47  Active

I am attempting to add:

```
    public override void ParseEntity(ref ApplicationUser entity)
    {
        entity.Email = Email;
        entity.UserName = Email;
        entity.FirstName = FirstName;
        entity.LastName = LastName;
        entity.UserTypeID = UserTypeID;
        entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.ModifiedBy = Id;
    }
```

to my IdentityModel.cs. The ApplicaionUser looks as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            // Add any custom User properties/code here 
        }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Guarantee Limit")]
        public Nullable<double> GuaranteeLimit { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User Type")]
        public int UserTypeID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Terms And Conditions Version")]
        public string TermsAndConditionsVersion { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Terms And Conditions Date")]
        public DateTime ? LastTermsAndConditionsDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Login Date And Time")]
        public DateTime ? LastLoginDateTime { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Created Date")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Modified Date")]
        public DateTime ? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Modified By")]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

/////////////////I want to add the override here/////////////////

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Am I able to add an override here or am I missing something? I have looked as some posts and tried the recommendation of adding using System.Web.Mvc but this makes no difference, same error message.

Comment: There is no method `ParseEntity` anywhere. Remove `override` and you'll be fine if you want to use it

Answer (score 1):

Your ApplicationUser is **implementing** the IdentityUser interface. Interfaces have nothing to override. Your ApplicationUser class must **inherit** from another class that has ParseEntity as either a virtual or abstract method in order to **override** it.

Comment: `IdentityUser` is a class, not an interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser(v=vs.108).aspx), so the first part of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed that IdentityUser wasn't an interface. So what class calls ParseEntity? From there you should be able to see what that class expects wether it can work with an interface or if it has to be a class. Hopefully an interface and then you can just add that to your ApplicationUser. If not, you may need to have ApplicationUser implement all the interfaces that IdentityUser implements in order to get it all wired up.

Comment: OK, thanks for your inputs. I was following an example in the project I'm working on which was using an override, but I don't need to overrride so removing it and having public void ParseEntity(ref ApplicationUser entity) works perfectly. Thanks for your help guys.